# Android studio Error: cannot resolve setText(double)

Tags: java, android-studio

I am a begineer at android studio and java . I have just started learning and i am stuck at this error.

I tried doing "int pound = 2 * kg" but it crashes the program when the button is pressed.

Pls help and here is the code:

```
package com.AR.converto;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button button;
    private TextView textView;
    private EditText kgval;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        kgval = findViewById(R.id.kgval);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //TOAST--> It is a short msg displayed below
                //Toast.makeText(peekAvailableContext(),"Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String s = kgval.getText().toString();
                int kg = Integer.parseInt(s);
                double pound = 2.2 * kg;

                textView.setText(pound);

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: You should be passing a string into `setText`. `textView.setText(String.valueOf(...))`

Answer (score 0):

You can only put String or Spannable into `TextView`.
If you want to put that number, try:

```
textView.setText((Double.tostring(pound)));
```

If it still crash, maybe you're not identified it yet. Try:

```
(textView.findById(R.id."your textview id")).setText((Double.tostring(pound)));
```

Is `textView` really the id for the `TextView` you mentioned?
If not, have you put an id in xml where that `TextView` created?